# rails skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am needing to post from an office computer via a ruby script to a remote  server.  I have put

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

in the controller yet every time I try I get "The change you wanted was rejected" and when I look at the log I get

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Am I misunderstanding something?
Here is the code from the ruby script

```
   url="display_ad[title]=#{row[1]}"
   date_arr = row[2].split('/')
   start_date = date_arr[2].to_s + "-" + date_arr[0].to_s + "-" + date_arr[1].to_s
   url+="&display_ad[start_date]=#{start_date}"

   date_arr = row[3].split('/')
   end_date = Date.new( date_arr[2].to_i,  date_arr[0].to_i,  date_arr[1].to_i )
   end_date = end_date + 7
   end_date = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
   url+="&display_ad[end_date]=#{end_date}"
   url+="&display_ad[slug]=#{row[7]}"
   url+="&display_ad[category]=othr"
   url = url.gsub("\n","")
   url = url.gsub("\r","")
   p url
   easy =  Curl::Easy.http_post("http://example.com/advertising/web/web_service_add", url)
```

And in the controller action

```
 ad = DisplayAds.new(params[:display_ad])
 ad.save
```

Comment: Can you give a little more details on your code?

Comment: It's really weird that skipping filter didn't help but you can try `protect_from_forgery :only => []`

Comment: sadly, I had to change it to GET because of time constraints.

Comment: protect_from_forgery :only => []  didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this page after having the same issue with a Rails 2.3.8 project. I use `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in several controllers successfully, but this was the first time I had tried to use it at the top of the `ApplicationController` class on an action defined in the application controller.

I moved my action to another controller, along with the skip_before_filter line and the verification was correctly disabled, as expected. I think that maybe the issue is that this does not work as you might expect when used directly in the application controller for actions defined in that class. I have not investigated why that might be, since it was lazy coding on my part that the specific action I was struggling with had been defined there, so moving it was a better option anyway. Others experiencing this problem should try moving their affected actions out of the `ApplicationController` class.

Interestingly, in a Rails 3.2.1 project I have used `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in the `ApplicationController` with an action defined in the class and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

please check your code whether this line:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

It will start the csrf protection.
Keep in mind that put all your sckip_before_filter alike after this method.

Gook Luck!

Comment: doesn't work for API only mode. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266207/rails-before-process-action-callback-authenticate-user-has-not-been-defined) asnwer by Philnash, it solved my problem.