# Rails: Before process_action callback :authenticate_user! has not been defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, twilio, ngrok

I'm creating a rails app that includes devise.
I'm trying to add Twilio messaging to my site with Ngrok, i used this tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/04/receive-and-reply-to-sms-in-rails.html

I was able to open Ngrok in the console and get the web-id they give for my url.
I keep getting this error when I plug the url into my browser ..I'm supposed to get to my own rails local app. Not sure whats wrong.

What I added in my messaging controller made for ngrok:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => "reply"

def reply
   message_body = params["Body"]
   from_number = params["From"]
   boot_twilio
   sms = @client.messages.create(
     from: Rails.application.secrets.twilio_number,
     to: from_number,
     body: "Hello there, thanks for texting me. Your number is #{from_number}."
  )
  #twilio expects a HTTP response to this request
end


private
 def boot_twilio
   account_sid = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid
   auth_token = Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
   @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
 end
end
```

really unsure what is wrong.
when its not connecting to the 'def reply' and authenticate_user should be defined by devise.

Comment: What error do you mean? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: The error is "ArgumentError in MessagesController#reply" "Before process_action callback :authenticate_user! has not been defined"

Comment: and it highlights the line "skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => "reply""

Comment: When I remove that line, i get this error: " NameError in MessagesController#reply" ..."
uninitialized constant MessagesController::Twilio". this highlights the code ```    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token```

Comment: OK, still looking into your first error, but that second one sounds like you haven't installed the Twilio gem. Add `gem 'twilio-ruby'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and try that again.

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 or 5?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like this was a problem that Rails 5 seems to have introduced. If the filter hasn't been defined by the time it is used in a controller it will raise an error. [This was discovered in the Clearance project too](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/621).

[Their fix](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/pull/626) was to pass the `raise: false` option to `skip_before_filter`:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => "reply", :raise => false

end
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue to this when I was working on a **Rails 6** application with **Devise** gem for authentication and authorization.

I added a `skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index, :show]` to the **Products** controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

And it was throwing the error below when I visit the **Products** page:

```
Before process_action callback :authenticate_admin! has not been defined
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

To use the `skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index, :show]` in the **Products** controller, I first needed to define the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the `application_controller`:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_admin!

end
```

Now I can use the `skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index, :show]` in the **Products** controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

An alternative, if I don't want to define the `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the `application_controller` is to use the `before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :show]`:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It makes the whole sense after reading this. Because authenticate_admin is a devise method, it's not a callback out of the box.